# CPQ - Disable Proration

Tags: cpq-plugins

Does anyone have a workaround for disabling proration on a subscription product?

Price rules are not working or cause issues down the line
I found a solution in the community where a developer accessed the Custom Script Object and set the ‘calculateFullTermPrice’ attribute to true to disable proration. But having issues locating it.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but there is a documented approach now using the Salesforce Quote Calculator Plugin.
You can access the **calculateFullTermPrice** property of a quote line in the init method as shown below:

```
export function onInit(quoteLineModels) {
    if (!quoteLineModels) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < quoteLineModels.length; i++) {
        if (quoteLineModels[i].record["SBQQ__Product__r"]["DisableProration__c"]) {
            quoteLineModels[i].calculateFullTermPrice = true;
        }
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
};
```

You can also create a custom field on Product and check for that field in your script.

I also include a link to my blog post where I go in depth into this solution and possible architecture updates. Please note that this is my website and i'm therefore affiliated to it:
https://salesforceninjacom.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/cpq-ninja-disable-subscription-price-proration-for-specific-products/

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam.
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.